# tensorflow saves only the initialized value

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to save some variables and see if I could restore it later. 
Here is my saving code:

```
   import tensorflow as tf;
   my_a = tf.Variable(2,name = "my_a");
   my_b = tf.Variable(3,name = "my_b");
   my_c = tf.Variable(4,name = "my_c");
   my_c = tf.add(my_a,my_b);

   with tf.Session() as sess:
       init = tf.initialize_all_variables();
       sess.run(init);
       print("my_c =  ",sess.run(my_c));
       saver = tf.train.Saver();
       saver.save(sess,"test.ckpt");
```

This prints out:

```
    my_c =   5
```

As I restore it:

```
   import tensorflow as tf;
   c = tf.Variable(3100,dtype = tf.int32);
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables());
       saver = tf.train.Saver({"my_c":c});
       saver.restore(sess, "test.ckpt");
       cc= sess.run(c);
       print(cc);
```

This gives me :

```
    4
```

The restored value of my_c should be 5 since it is the sum of my_a and my_b. However it gives me 4, which is the initialized value of my_c. Could anyone explain why that happens, and how to save the changes to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, you have not really assigned the variable named `my_c` (mind you, TensorFlow `name`) to `my_a + my_b`.

By writing `my_c = tf.add(my_a,my_b)`, the python variable `my_c` is now different from the `tf.Variable` having `name='my_c'`.

When you execute `sess.run()`, you are just executing the operation, not updating that variable.

If you want this code to run correctly, use this instead - (see the comments for changes)

```
import tensorflow as tf
my_a = tf.Variable(2,name = "my_a")
my_b = tf.Variable(3,name = "my_b")
my_c = tf.Variable(4,name="my_c")
# Use the assign() function to set the new value
add = my_c.assign(tf.add(my_a,my_b))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    # Execute the add operator
    sess.run(add)
    print("my_c =  ",sess.run(my_c))
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess,"test.ckpt")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Using your code, it reports the error when I load the model: NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Tensor name "my_c" not found in checkpoint files test.ckpt

Comment: sorry, check the new answer. My old answer wasn't creating a variable. Only variables are saved by TensorFlow, not Tensors

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way to change the named variable without defining an operation variable or assigning values? This seems a little bit complicated and not convenient  if I have a lot of operations...

Comment: The official docs seem to say that you have to use `assign()`. In most cases, you won't need to save everything to be honest https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/variables#Variable

Comment: That is true. Thanks!